# How to strlen of a multi-language string

Tags: php, multilingual, strlen

I want to get strlen() of Shift-jis and Utf-8, then compare them.
A string could be mixed "ああ12345678sdfdszzz". I tried to use strlen but it generates the different results. mb_strlen also doesn't help because this is a mixed string.

For example:

```
ああ12345678 >> strlen() = 24 chars
ああああああああああああああああ >> strlen() = 48 chars
ああああああああああああああああああ >> strlen() = 54 chars
```

It seems to be there is no rule. So **what is the best way to calculate strlen and compare them in multilanguage**?

Comment: Judging from your examples, the `あ` in your two latter examples are 3 bytes each (might be UTF-8 then). But that doesn’t quite correlate with the first example. So how exactly are these strings build?

Comment: That character is Hiragana. I typed using ibus keyboard on ubuntu. I don't know why it's 3 bytes. I think it must be 2 bytes. I wonder whether there is a real rule for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`strlen`](http://php.net/strlen) does only count the bytes and thus is only useful for [single-byte character encodings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SBCS); use [`mb_strlen`](http://php.net/mb_strlen) for [multi-byte character encodings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-byte_character_set) that can count the actual characters instead.

Comment: it is a mixed string, what encoding should I pass to mb_strlen? utf8 or sjis? What if they type 5 languages?

Comment: Then how are the character encodings mixed? Note that US-ASCII is a proper subset of the UCS and is encoded exactly in both US-ASCII and UTF-8.

Comment: I'm sorry but what encoding will you pass to mb_strlen? I mean the second parameter of mb_strlen.

Answer (score 2):

I would write a function to check from where to where a particular encoding exsist.

Then I would split the string into encodings, perform the mb_strlen and sum up the sizes afterwords. Then repeat on the second string and compare.

I guess you understand my point ;)

PS: Use mb_detect_encoding to detect encoding

[mb_detect_encoding (see the comments for further ideas by the php community)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$field = $_POST['field'];
$field_length = mb_strlen($field,'utf-8');
```